# Extra space is added at the bottom of text in uitextview when string is pasted into it

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift4, uitextviewdelegate

When i am pasting the text in `UITextView` then some extra space is getting added into it. But when i scroll it then the `textView` is fitted according to the content. In `textViewDidChange`, `textView` height constraint is being set according to its content size. Anybody faced the same issue?

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    if newSize.height < 37 {
        self.messageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = minimumTextviewHeight
    }
    if (newSize.height >= 37 && newSize.height <= 100) {
        self.messageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
    }
    if (newSize.height >= 100) {
        self.messageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = maximumTextviewHeight
        self.textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: @s-v : TextView when scroll disabled gets intrinsic size from content set, if you are setting height constraint manually u might be affecting the content size of textView. So show us the code where u set the constraint

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the textView's smartInsertDeleteType to .no

```
textView.smartInsertDeleteType = .no
```

Reference link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865828-smartinsertdeletetype